# A duplicate field name <name> was found while adding a column to a content type

Tags: content-type, site-column, duplicate

I have a content type `Custom Page` and I have created a site column called `CustomPageContentOne` (type - Publishing HTML).

When I add this column to the `Custom Page` content type from UI, it shows that A duplicate field name `CustomPageContentOne` was found. But there is no such field in this content type.
I checked if it already has a hidden field with this name using PowerShell script and it doesn't have this field. Yet it is showing such error.
Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: double check; use sharepoint manager if you can

Comment: Thanks, Tiago! Cannot install anything on the server, customer does not allow this. By the way, do you mean SharePoint Manager will show something PowerShell can't?

Comment: no not really. just that you can see with your own eyes. powershell should work but you have to be extra careful. are you querying the list? the list content type? or the site content type? perhaps the column is there but at a different scope. maybe you can add some screen shots and check ULS for helpful messages. sometimes sharepoint designer can help as well

Comment: The ULS doesn't have any more information either, except for the same error "A duplicate field anme <fieldname> was found".

Comment: I think that you'll have to either provide us some code/screen shots or otherwise make some trial and error as jenny suggested. don't simply trust powershell. btw you don't have to install manager, it's just an .exe that you can run locally in prod, or in a dev if you ask a backup of the database

Comment: Thanks, Tiago! Looks like I'm gonna have to try something else. I wasn't trusting the PowerShell alone, I am able to create the Site Column with this name, which says a lot about that column not being anywhere in the site collection already.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to try to rectify the issue is to rename your custom site column.  If that works, I would assume that another column called **CustomPageContentOne** exists somewhere in your site collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm quite sure that the site collection does not have this site column. The fact that the powershell script doesn't return this column and I can create this column (with the given name and type) in site columns after which it doesn't show error that this name already exists, clearly shows that there is no column with this name. When I add this column to a content type, it shows the error that I posted.